# Dispatch right after another dispatch overwrites state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm new to React and react-redux and I'm having a lot of trouble with dispatches and updating the state

After the response from the server, if the user is authenticated I proceed to do below

```
this.props.dispatch(addAuth(logged.user));
this.props.dispatch(updateAvatar(logged.user.avatar))
```

However, after I do that the log is

```
{type: "AUTHENTICATE", user: "cash"} //(LOGGING ACTION FROM REDUCER)
{isAuth: true, username: "cash", myAvatar: undefined, dispatch: ƒ}

{type: "UPDATE_AVATAR", updateAvatar: "http://www.example.com/1234.jpg"} //(LOGGING ACTION FROM REDUCER)
{isAuth: undefined, username: undefined, myAvatar: undefined, dispatch: ƒ}
```

Here's the initial state

```
const intialState = {
    isAuth: false,
    username: '',
    myAvatar: ''
};
```

Actions

```
function addAuth(user){
    return {
        type: 'AUTHENTICATE', 
        user: user.username,
    };

}

function updateAvatar(avatarLink){
    return {
        type: 'UPDATE_AVATAR', 
        updateAvatar: avatarLink
    };
}
```

Reducer

```
function reducer(state = intialState, action) {
    switch(action.type){
        case 'AUTHENTICATE':
        return {
            isAuth: true,
            username: action.user,
        };
        case 'LOGOUT':
        return {
            isAuth: false
        }
        case 'UPDATE_AVATAR':
        return {
            myAvatar: action.updateAvatar
        };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

My desired outcome is to update the isAuth and username and then just update the avatar state like so

```
{isAuth: true, username: "cash", myAvatar: undefined, dispatch: ƒ}
{isAuth: true, username: "cash", myAvatar: "http://www.example.com/1234.jpg", dispatch: ƒ}
```

Comment: How does `addAuth` work (async call to server in middleware, for example)? What does it return? How do you get the `avatarLink`?

Comment: @OriDrori As soon as my App.js component mounts I make a request to the server to see if there's a session using Passport.js and to get that user from the database. So, I get the user and then query database for their profile image and  return that in an object called user. so it'd be user = { username: 'cash', avatar: 'example.jpg' } and I just pass in those properties to the different actions

Comment: How do you query the server (thunk, api middleware, etc...)?

Comment: @OriDrori using Fetch API, I'm using Express and Mongoose on the backend

Comment: But how do call the Fetch API from redux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your return a new object without specifying all properties, leaving some undefined.

If you want to create a copy of the old state and alter this new object `Object.assign` should be what you are looking for. According to [redux docs](https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers#handling-actions) this should be the reducer for your `AUTHENTICATE` action:

```
return Object.assign({}, state, {
    isAuth: true,
    username: action.username
})
```

The other actions can be rewritten the same way, if you intend to copy the other unspecified values.

A note from [the docs](https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers#handling-actions):

> We don't mutate the state. We create a copy with `Object.assign()`.
>   `Object.assign(state, { visibilityFilter: action.filter })` is also
>   wrong: it will mutate the first argument. You must supply an empty
>   object as the first parameter. You can also enable the object spread
>   operator proposal to write `{ ...state, ...newState }` instead.

Comment: Exactly what my problem was! Thank you so much!! I've been having trouble with wrapping my head around redux

Comment: @tkss glad i could help. Please select one of the answers as the correct answer.